# Export Excel workbook with many worksheets to XML or CSV

Tags: xml, excel, vbscript

I have a project to upload the data in many excel workbooks, each containing many worksheets that all have different columns. Fortunately all the workbooks are in the same format. Is there a programmatic way to loop through these worksheets to export it into one flat file in XML or CSV?  I have experimented with ETL tools, but all of them expect the schema across the worksheets to be the same, and there are over 100 columns to contend with. From perusing many forums it seems that there should be a way to do this using VB, but I have no VB experience.

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Excel to XML Exporter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel2xml.aspx) presented on CodeProject.  It may be just what you need.